# Overlapping relatively positioned objects after a jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, css, html, overlapping

So I've looked around quite a bit for an example to this but I couldn't find anything for what exactly I am trying to do.

I'm building a blog with the front page having a bunch of posts in order like this -

http://prntscr.com/1vjoun

The blogs vary in size based on how much text is in them -

http://prntscr.com/1vjozq

When you hover over a blog I am trying to make a small bar appear inside of the blog that overlaps the text at the bottom so that I can have some options appear, such as 'Like' 'Favorite' 'Feature' or w/e and this is where my problem comes in.

```
echo "<div class='blogpost' id='" . $row['blogid'] . "'>";
echo "<h3 class='blogheader'>" . $row['blogheader'] . "</h3>";
echo "<p class='blogbody'>" . $row['blogbody'] . "</p>";
echo "<div class='blogextras'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

I create the 'blogextras' div that will hold the options mentioned above.

```
.blogextras {
    position:relative;
    height:35px;
    width:100%;
    background:#333;
}
```

I give it some style.

```
    $(".blogpost").hover(function(){
$(".blogpost").css("overflow", "auto");
$(".blogextras").show();
$(".blogextras").css("position", "absolute");
});

  $(".blogpost").mouseleave(function(){
$(".blogpost").css("overflow", "hidden");
$(".blogextras").hide();
$(".blogextras").css("position", "relative");
  });
```

Add some jQuery.

But my final result makes the 'blogextras' div appear below where I want it to be (about 35 pixels) -

http://prntscr.com/1vjppq

I also tried not changing it's position from relative to absolute and this does give a kind of desired result except it makes the boxes re-size which I don't want it to do.

I want the 'blogextras' div to appear at the bottom of the visible text area every time no matter the size of the 'blogpost' div.

Sorry if I haven't been discriptive enough or haven't given enough code just post a comment if you want to see more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.blogpost` container needs a relative position so that you can position your `.blogextras` bar exactly within that container. You also need to give the `.blogextras` bar a higher `z-index` so that it overlaps the `.blogpost` content:

```
.blogpost {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    /* Other CSS */
}
.blogextras {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    height:35px;
    width:100%;
    background:#333;
}

$(".blogpost").hover(function(){
    $(".blogextras").fadeIn();
});

$(".blogpost").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".blogextras").fadeOut();
});
```

Untested, but that should give you ~ what you need.

Comment: I did all that and it creates the blogextras bar within the blogpost but at the bottom underneath all the text, it still doesn't overlap?
http://prntscr.com/1vjtmi

Comment: Why is there a scrollbar? Have you set `overflow:hidden;` ?

Comment: Yes but the way I have it in jquery is that on hover overflow:auto; and I tried it without it changing the overflow and you just cant see the blogextras bar (assuming its below all the text at a point you can't see without overflow)

Comment: I was able to fix it using what you told me plus adding 

.blogextras {
bottom:0px;
}

Thank you very much for your help! It was my fault for not seeing you did it.